I'm trying to change a label in ASP.NET in a public function and I get an error
public string CheckStatus(int status)
{
    string Ticket;

    switch (status) 
    {
        case 1:
            Ticket = "Open";
            return Ticket;

        case 2:
            Ticket = "Pending";
            return Ticket;

        case 3:
            Ticket = "In Progress";
            return Ticket;

        case 4:
            Ticket = "Escalated";
            return Ticket;

        case 5:
            Ticket = "Closed";
            return Ticket;

        default:
            Ticket = "Null";
            return Ticket;

            lblStatus.Text = ("Status: " + Ticket);
    }
}


Warning CS0162 Unreachable code detected
AS-Ticketing-Systems  C:\Users\s0300060\Downloads\AS-Ticketing-Systems\AS-Ticketing-Systems\webpages\itsupport\SelectedItTicket.aspx.cs   141 Active

I want it to change the label to the string tickets

You have return statements before you assign

That's a warning, not an error. Your code compiled successfully and will run. It's just the compiler telling you something looks a little off.

The warning (not error) is telling you something doesn't look right. Taking a look at the code the line below is unreachable and may as well be removed.
            lblStatus.Text = ("Status: " + Ticket);

If you need that statement to do something it's probably in the wrong place!
What I think you meant was this.
public string CheckStatus(int status)
{
    string Ticket;

    switch (status) 
    {
        case 1:
            Ticket = "Open";
            break;

        case 2:
            Ticket = "Pending";
            break;

        case 3:
            Ticket = "In Progress";
            break;

        case 4:
            Ticket = "Escalated";
            break;

        case 5:
            Ticket = "Closed";

        default:
            Ticket = "Null";
    }

    lblStatus.Text = ("Status: " + Ticket);
    return Ticket;
}

Switch Expression
.NET introduced switch expressions that would simplify this even further but you've tagged [asp.net] rather than [asp.net-core]. Just in case though (and with a little tidying up)...
public string CheckStatus(int status)
{
    var ticket = status switch
    {
        1 => "Open",
        2 => "Pending",
        3 => "In Progress",
        4 => "Escalated",
        5 => "Closed",
        _ => "Null",
    }

    lblStatus.Text = $"Status: {ticket}";
    return ticket;
}


Unreachable code is caused by the return statement in default block of code:
default:
    Ticket = "Null";
    return Ticket; //there it is. Even compiler should give you the warning here

    lblStatus.Text = ("Status: " + Ticket);

The solution is to simply bring return statement to the end of your default block:
default:
    Ticket = "Null";
    
    lblStatus.Text = ("Status: " + Ticket);
    return Ticket;

Also the good tip is to use break keywork in each case and default blocks and simply in the end of the method write return Ticket:
public string CheckStatus(int status)
{

    string Ticket;
    switch (status) 
    {
        case 1:
            Ticket = "Open";
            break;
        case 2:
            Ticket = "Pending";
            break;
        case 3:
            Ticket = "In Progress";
            break;
        case 4:
            Ticket = "Escalated";
            break;
        case 5:
            Ticket = "Closed";
            break;
        default:
            Ticket = "Null";
            lblStatus.Text = ("Status: " + Ticket);
            break;

    }
    return Ticket;
}

Or you can even simplify your code like this:
public string CheckStatus(int status)
{
    switch (status) 
    {
        case 1: return "Open";
        case 2: return "Pending";
        case 3: return "In Progress";
        case 4: return "Escalated";
        case 5: return "Closed";
        default:
            lblStatus.Text = "Status: Null";
            return "Null";

    }
}


Hey thanks for this. I tried to return the code to the page load function as that's the page which originally was setting the label to the status in my database. However for it to update upon the user clicking the button you need to reload the page 2 times. as for some reason it would reload the page before the code was able to update the database and change the label.

if your problem is not solved yet please describe it more clearly. Update your answer and add missed details

Careful when using page load event. For any button click, or post-back from a control, the page load event will re-run, and THEN your code stub for that control runs. So, just keep in mind that page load will run each time, and run before your button or control stub runs. As a result, near EVERY web page will have a if (!IsPostBack) {real first page load code goes here} is required to build a proper working web page. So, code to load controls, and setup controls can be placed in page load event, but it MUST be inside of that !IsPostBack code stub, else it runs each and every time.
